# Here do i need to fix price for my ERC20 token per Ether?

Tags: solidity

Suppose I minted 1000 erc20 token, I named it ABI. Now I wanna make a dapp where users can buy our token by giving Ether. For this case:

1. As I made my own erc20 token will I have to fix it's price for Ether?? Like 1 Ether = 20 ABI. If not then how to do it?
2. Write me a demo function for this functionality.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Basically you can write whatever you want in your sale contract. Here's an old OZ reference: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol

Comment: I will have to write this contract in rust, can u give me any helpful reference to implement this logic?

Comment: You can't write Ethereum contracts in Rust.